# Number Picker Android Visual Bug

Tags: android, android-layout

The below code give horizontal number picker.
But it's visual gives some shadow for both + and - button.
How do overcome this problem. Buttons are Half view need full view.
[image]

```
 <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/seconds"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>
```

Full layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/seconds"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please, provide the whole layout.

Comment: Below is the full layout.                                           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
 <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/seconds"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

</LinearLayout>

Answer (score 0):

The error might be because of the semicolon (`;`) after the `xmlns:android="..."` in the `LinearLayout` tag.

Comment: Hi i checked ; which not in my original code. that ; is added by stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Parent layout hasn't free space for NumberPicker

Set `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to it.